# Next js how to avoid re-rendering of common components between routed pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have set up the basic router in Next js and I want multiple pages to share a component e.g. a header. The shared component is reloading on each new page load. (How) can I reuse components without rerendering them needlessly between page loads? This is really inefficient compared to CRA + react-router nested routing removing the requirement for any form of shared components.

Sandox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-sandbox-demo-vs2yb)

Shared component code as follows:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

export default function hello() {}

export const Header = memo(() => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Next js Shared component</h1>
      <p>{Math.random()}</p>
    </>
  );
});
```

I have tried wrapping a common component in a memo to try to avoid rerender but that doesn't work. Is there a way to share components between pages in Next JS?

Comment: how you are consuming?

Comment: exactly as in the codesandbox example

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nextjs. You are mounting shared component two times inside two pages. It order to achieve described behaviour, you have to have only one, let's say Layout component spawned with using custom App or _document component. Checkout this [this article](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place your shared components like `Header` inside `_app.js`, and remove from other components, like below:

```
// /pages/_app_.js
import React from "react";
import { Wrapper, Header } from "../common";

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <Header/>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: What about if the shared components is something that should go inside a grid in the page? How would you shared that internal component?